# Define the height of div box (bottom) vs different resolutions

Tags: css, height, positioning, resolution

I have a problem with setting the appropriate text to the slider. I want the text to appear on the bottom right of the page. Only problem is the different resolutions (tablet, laptop, 24'' monitor).

Testing page: http://tinyurl.com/d825kuv

code:

```
div {
 position:relative; 
 float:right; 
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
position:absolute;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
```

This will make sure that the element in question will be as far right, and as far down within the parent as possible. Of course if you wanted to pad it from the right/bottom just take the pixels up a notch. Note that position:absolute only works if the parent's position is not set as default. If in doubt give your parent the following style:

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, so I tried and did not work. Now you can see: http://tinyurl.com/d825kuv

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? The site looks fine (Really attractive, in fact) to me.

Comment: now you just need to adjust the 0px values for right and bottom, trial and error should get you there pretty fast, try changing to 100px to see the direction each attribute controls, then tailor to your neeed

Comment: Sorry, I have noticed that your trying to push the element in question to the bottom of the 'container' div. This container does not stretch to the bottom of the page, which is why the element is not displayed at the bottom.

Comment: If it was me, I would give the div a set appropriate height (lets say 200px). Then put the div inside the controls-wrapper div and then give the div `position:absolute; top:-200px;right:0;` Purely because the controls-wrapper is always stuck to the bottom, meaning the text div will always stick with it. Give it a try (:

Answer (score 2):

to move an element to the bottom of a `<div>`, set the parent `<div>`'s position to relative:  `position:relative`, then the `<div>` you want to be placed at the bottom should have CSS

```
div {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right:0;
}
```

then just adjust the pixel values to suit your layout.

Comment: Unfortunately, so I tried and did not work. Now you can see: http://tinyurl.com/d825kuv